# How do I view vote count split in documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation, voting, privileges, vote-count

Currently, I cannot see the vote counts (up/down) in documentations. Is this another privilege?

Comment: I can't access the breakdown in the usual manner either. I'm expecting this was something they planned to add later after the major concerns are resolved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

This isn't implemented yet like it is in Q&A. It will make it eventually, but it's not officially on a roadmap (yet).

Comment: meta-tag:status-planned-eventually

Comment: There are a lot of little improvements that need to be added that just haven't made it to the top of the list yet, but it wasn't intentionally excluded. It will make it eventually, though. No, it's not officially on a roadmap.

Comment: @DavidG, He's a creative director at Stack Exchange (verified employee).  If he says it's planned, it's very likely planned.

Comment: So that's the *second* time I've been burned by getting a response from an employee without a diamond near their name...Alrighty then. :)

Comment: @Makoto I use [SOX](http://stackapps.com/q/6091/34727), which has a feature that puts a Stack Overflow icon next to employees’ names, so you don’t get surprised.

Comment: @Makoto not trying to burn you. Yeah, we should probably have a differentiator. The diamond stands for mod, which I'm really not.

Comment: I'm guessing some time in 6-8 weeks?